# Eclipse properties panel error

Tags: eclipse

Each time i launch the properties panel i get this error:

> Could not accept change: the currently
>   displayed page contains invalid
>   values.

I have tried to use a fresh new workspace & a new install of eclipse without any result.

I am on mac OS X.

Any help wellcome

screen captures of the problem:

[alt text http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/1.jpg](http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/1.jpg)
[alt text http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/2.jpg](http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/2.jpg)
[alt text http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/3.jpg](http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/3.jpg)

Here 2 new screen capture (fresh new loaded eclipse + new workspace)
[alt text http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/4.jpg](http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/4.jpg)
[alt text http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/5.jpg](http://www.neverblind.eu/eclipse_error/5.jpg)

I found the error on the eclipse workspace .log file :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2010-05-21 18:24:06.148
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:804)
    at com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.getInstanceInternal(Calendar.java:1630)
    at com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1594)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat.get(DateFormat.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.java:1078)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.IDEResourceInfoUtils.getDateStringValue(IDEResourceInfoUtils.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.ResourceInfoPage.createStateGroup(ResourceInfoPage.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.ResourceInfoPage.createContents(ResourceInfoPage.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1124)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(PreferenceDialog.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$4.run(PreferenceDialog.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createContents(PreferenceDialog.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PropertyDialog.createDialogOn(PropertyDialog.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.createDialog(PropertyDialogAction.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3543)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1273)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3100)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Comment: What exact property panel are you trying to see (which displays the error message)?

Comment: This happens to me on the CDT. Basically the error is saying that the current window has an invalid setting, usually  the offending item will be marked by an (!) in a triangle or and (x) in a circle. Try to fix or delete that item and see if that helps.

Comment: @VonC evrey "Properties" panel (properties of project, file, folder)

Comment: @iondiode after the error message the propertie panel open but there is no item marked with ! or X

Comment: you've tried a new workspace and a new install of eclipse. Are you opening the same projects? Is anything non-writable or in a non writable directory? By anything, i mean project files, workspace or executable( eclipse itself). Can you post a capture of the window with error? does the preferences window give you the same problem?

Comment: Does the Error View or the logfile (in the workspace directory) contain more details? A screenshot maybe helpful; also try "Reset perspective".

Comment: @vs no changes after reseting the perspective.
I will post a link to a screenshot soon
Thank U All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse sometimes behaves in weird manner. All all your source code folders ok? Please check all folder first. If they are ok then there must be something with the core plugins OR the workspace in which you have all your projects.

First copy your workspace, then install another instance of eclipse. Try to open the workspace in that eclipse.

If that doesn't work, it seems a big problem. May be you need to import all projects again in new workspace.

For better performance, you should keep number of projects in workspace somewhat limited. It seems you have many projects inside one workspace which might cause memory problems and slower your eclipse.

I hope, this works for you.

---EDIT on 21st May,2010---

After searching it ,it seems a bug in eclipse 3.4. Thought it shows a bug of WinXP, may be it affects MAC also.

Please check the link below. They have specified version 3.4 M6.

So if you are using older version of eclipse then please get newer from this link.
Also please check to have JDK 1.6 (Stable version) installed on your mac.

Eclipse download: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=217707

Hope this helps.

thanks.

Comment: hi, I installed a fresh new eclipse + new empty workspace, but the probleme remain ! look at the screen capture !

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the Console (Applications -> Utilities -> Console.app) and see whether there are any specific messages from eclipse (and post them here if possible)? 
A exception stack trace or something?

Maybe it might throw some light on whats going wrong.